# counter with multiple digits

Tags: javascript, counter, digits

I'm fairly new to Javascript and have been able to get by so far by just following tutorials and reading forums but this one really stumped me for a while.

Basically I wanted to have a counter for numbers that contain seven digits, I found a few things but none that really made sense to me so I wrote this:

```
imgNumber++;
if (imgNumber < 10){function add(number){return '00000' + number}};
if (imgNumber > 10 && imgNumber < 100){function add(number){return '0000' + number}};
if (imgNumber > 100 && imgNumber < 1000){function add(number){return '000' + number}};
if (imgNumber > 1000 && imgNumber < 10000){function add(number){return '00' + number}};
if (imgNumber > 10000 && imgNumber < 100000){function add(number){return '0' + number}};
if (imgNumber > 100000 && imgNumber < 1000000){function add(number){return '' + number}};
```

It works as far as I can tell.  My question is this: Do you foresee any issues with this and if not is there a cleaner way to write all this?

I'll appreciate any and all replys.

Cheers,
Colin

Answer (score 2):

As with all programming functions are your friend.  I searched google for padding zeros javascript and got directed to [this site](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/pad-number-zeroes-javascript/).

```
function pad(number, length) {
       var negative = number < 0;
       var str = '' + Math.abs(number);
       while (str.length < length) {
           str = '0' + str;
       }
       if(negative) str = '-' + str;
    return str;
}
```

Using this you would just generate your number standard and prior to storing/outputting it you'd run it through this function:

```
pad(1,7);
```

Comment: +1 for a decent response - I don't know if Javascript has an issue with string concat being very slow for large repetitions or not (not a JS guy). If 'length' is going to be huge, it might be worth finding a more efficient method. But the readability of the function makes up for the slowness, especially if `length` will always be small.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot.  You know I usually don't resort to posting cause I know the answers out there, I guess the term 'padding' completely slipped my mind.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's a valid critique, Gareve has a good alternative below.

Comment: String concatenation shouldn't cause a performance issue, since the strings are going to be short anyway. This is probably just as fast as any other solution. It won't work correctly on negative numbers though if that's a possibility, e.g. `pad(-3, 5) === "000-3"`.

Comment: I updated the answer to support negative numbers, thanks for the observation Matthew Crumley

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
var output = sprintf("%07d", 30);
```

Believe me, it will save you a lot of time in javascript (and in other languages). You can download the implementation in http://sprintf.googlecode.com/files/sprintf-0.7-beta1.js

By today, this code works right now, perhaps you need to change the src of the library for a more updated:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sprintf.googlecode.com/files/sprintf-0.7-beta1.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
   alert(sprintf("%04d",4));
</script>
```

More information, [here](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf), plus there are other implementations of this useful method.

Comment: You know I've used sprintf() in the past in other applications but never thought about implementing it with javascript, guess I just didn't think I could.  This will save me a tremendous amount of time.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the log (base 10) of the number as an indicator of how many digits to add.

If log(N) is between 0 and less than 1, N is  a one digit number.
If log(N) is greater than or equal to 1 but less than 2, N has two digits, and so forth.

I don't actually code in JavaScript, so I don't know if you have access to a log function, but if you do, this is a very terse way to get the result.

John Doner